# Can a cassandra table be queried using only a part of the composite partition key?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql

Consider a table like this to store a user's contacts -

```
CREATE TABLE contacts {
    user_name text,
    contact_name text,
    contact_id int, 
    contact_data blob,
    PRIMARYKEY ((user, contact_name), contact_id)
    //          ^-- Note the composite partition key
}
```

The composite partition key results in a row per contact.

Let's say there are a 100 million users and every user has a few hundred contacts.

I can look up a particular user's particular contact's data by using

```
SELECT contact_data FROM contacts WHERE user_name='foo' AND contact_name='bar'
```

However, is it also possible to look up all contact names for a user using something like,

```
SELECT contact_name FROM contacts WHERE user_name='foo'
```

? could the WHERE clause contain only some of all the columns that form the primary key?

EDIT -- I tried this and cassandra doesn't allow it. So my question now is, how would you model the data to support two queries -

1. Get data for a specific user & contact
2. Get all contact names for a user

I can think of two options -

1. Create another table containing user_name and contact_name with only user_name as the primary key. But then if a user has too many contacts, could that be a wide row issue?
2. Create an index on user_name. But given 100M users with only a few hundred contacts per user, would user_name be considered a high-cardinality value hence bad for use in index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a RDBMS the query planner might be able to create an efficient query plan for that kind of query. But Cassandra can not. Cassandra would have to do a table scan. Cassandra tries hard not to allow you to make those kinds of queries. So it should reject it.

Comment: I just tried to verify and the result was as you pointed out. I've edited my question - could you comment about the two options I mentioned in the edit

Comment: @PuneetArora No, I won't. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: ok, no worries, I went ahead and asked that separately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488557/cassandra-data-modeling-for-one-to-many-lookup

Answer (score 1):

No You cannot. If you look at the mechanism of how cassandra stores data, you will understand why you cannot query by part of composite partition key.

Cassandra distributes data across nodes based on partition key. The co-ordinator of a write request generates hash token using murmur3 algorithm on partition key and sends the write request to the token's owner.(each node has a token range that it owns). During a read, a co-ordinator again calculates the hash token based on partition key and sends the read request to the token's owner node.

Since you are using composite partition key, during a write request, all components of key (user, contact_name) will be used to generate the hash token. The owner node of this token has the entire row. During a read request, you have to provide all components of the key to calculate the token and issue the read request to the correct owner of that token. Hence, Cassandra enforces you to provide the entire partition key.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different tables with same structure but not the same partition key :

`CREATE TABLE contacts {
    user_name text,
    contact_name text,
    contact_id int, 
    contact_data blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_name, contact_name), contact_id)
}
CREATE TABLE contacts_by_users {
    user_name text,
    contact_name text,
    contact_id int, 
    contact_data blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_name), contact_id)
}`

With this structure you have data duplication and you have to maintain both tables manually.

If you are using cassandra > 3.0, you can also use materialized views :

`CREATE TABLE contacts {
    user_name text,
    contact_name text,
    contact_id int, 
    contact_data blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_name, contact_name), contact_id)
}
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW contracts_by_users
AS
SELECT *
FROM contracts
WHERE user_name IS NOT NULL
    AND contract_name IS NOT NULL
    AND contract_id IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ((user_name), contract_name, contract_id)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY contract_name ASC`

In this case, you only have to maintain table `contracts`, the view will be automaticlly update

Comment: wouldn't it be better to have only user_name and contact_name in the contacts_by_user  table? The idea of the contacts table was not to store too much on a single partition. Consider contact_data to be a huge chuck

Comment: yes you can but you have to run an another query on contracts to get your contract data.

Comment: Ok. I didn't see the point of having contacts_by_user as well as contacts the way you put it. In that case contacts doesn't serve any purpose, since I'd end up getting contact's data in the first step itself